# Python Passing variables within (sub) functions

Tags: python, function, arguments

I am trying to understand a basic concept about passing variables and scoping in python but I am clearly missing something as I have spent a lot time reading but not getting what I am expecting.

I expect the following as:

1. Define global a in main ()
2. In define_stuff(), add a to 1 and assign to b, pass b or 3  back to main().
3. In add_stuff(), add a to b and assign c, pass c or 5 back to main().

   def main():
       a = '2'

   ```
   def define_stuff():
       b = 1 + float(a)
       print 'returning', b
       return b

   def add_stuff():
       print 'adding b to a ', 
       c = float(a) + float(b)
       print 'getting', c
       return c 

   define_stuff()
   add_stuff()
   ```

   if **name** == '**main**':
        main()

I am using 2.7. Clearly "return" does not perform what I am expecting.

What I need to do to pass a local variables within a (sub) function to main()?

```
returning 3.0
adding b to a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\scripts\testscope.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\scripts\testscope.py", line 16, in main
    add_stuff()
  File "C:\scripts\testscope.py", line 11, in add_stuff
    c = float(a) + float(b)
NameError: global name 'b' is not defined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `a` is not "global" in `main`, it is *local to `main`*. In any event, when you `return` a local variable from some function, it doesn't affect anything in the surrounding scope unless you *assign the return value in that scope*.

```
In [1]: def main():
   ...:     a = '2'
   ...:
   ...:     def define_stuff():
   ...:         b = 1 + float(a)
   ...:         print 'returning', b
   ...:         return b
   ...:
   ...:     def add_stuff():
   ...:         print 'adding b to a ',
   ...:         c = float(a) + float(b)
   ...:         print 'getting', c
   ...:         return c
   ...:
   ...:     b = define_stuff() # or else the value get's discarded
   ...:     c = add_stuff() # or else the value gets discarded
   ...:

In [2]: main()

returning 3.0
adding b to a  getting 5.0
```

Note, this is a brittle way to write code, since your `add_stuff` function depends on some non-local `b`, so if you want to use `add_stuff`, you *have to make sure* there is a `b` somewhere in variable resolution order (local, enclosing... global). Instead, it is a better practice to *only deal with local variables* and `return` values from functions and pass values as arguments to functions if the function will make use of them. Only use `global` variables sparingly. So, this would be better:

```
In [5]: def main():
   ...:
   ...:     def define_stuff(a):
   ...:         b = 1 + float(a)
   ...:         print 'returning', b
   ...:         return b
   ...:
   ...:     def add_stuff(a, b):
   ...:         print 'adding b to a ',
   ...:         c = float(a) + float(b)
   ...:         print 'getting', c
   ...:         return c
   ...:
   ...:     x = '2'
   ...:     y = define_stuff(x) # or else the value get's discarded
   ...:     z = add_stuff(x, y) # or else the value gets discarded
   ...:

In [6]: main()
returning 3.0
adding b to a  getting 5.0
```

Note, I've used `x, y, z` just to emphasize that these are separate, local variables, but you could have used `a,b,c`, but just remember, they don't have any intrinsic connection to the `a, b, c` in your inner function scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! It makes more sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`return b`returns the value of `b` alright, but it needs to be stored in a variable in `main`. The variable `b` is right now local to your function `add_stuff`. What you need is a variable `b` also in `main` to catch the value you return:

```
def main():
    a = '2'

    def define_stuff():
        b = 1 + float(a)
        print 'returning', b
        return b

    def add_stuff():
        print 'adding b to a ', 
        c = float(a) + float(b)
        print 'getting', c
        return c 

    b = define_stuff()
    c = add_stuff()

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

And in addition you probably want to catch the result of `add_stuff` also, in `c` as I have shown above.